# Using multiple datasets for one graph

Tags: r, plot

I have 2 csv data files. Each file has a "date_time" column and a "temp_c" column. I want to make the x-axis have the "date_time" from both files and then use 2 y-axes to display each "temp_c" with separate lines. I would like to use plot instead of ggplot2 if possible. I haven't been able to find any code help that works with my data and I'm not sure where to really begin. I know how to do 2 separate plots for these 2 datasets, just not combine them into one graph.

```
plot(grewl$temp_c ~ grewl$date_time)
```

and

```
plot(kbll$temp_c ~ kbll$date_time)
```

work separately but not together.

Comment: Look at `?points` or `?lines` for the base R way to add more data to an existing plot.

Comment: You should give a small sample of your two data sets so that we can help you. Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry. I'm very new at using R. will this help?   > head(grewl)
  grewingk_2     date_time temp_c humidity_rh dew_point         file_name
1          1 3/20/19 20:24   15.5        54.5       6.4 grewingk_2_050719
2          2 3/20/19 20:39   17.5        40.5       3.9 grewingk_2_050719
3          3 3/20/19 20:54   16.0        40.5       2.6 grewingk_2_050719
4          4 3/20/19 21:09   15.5        41.0       2.3 grewingk_2_050719
5          5 3/20/19 21:24   15.0        41.5       2.0 grewingk_2_050719
6          6 3/20/19 21:39   15.0        42.0       2.2 grewingk_2_050719

Comment: > head(kbll)
  KasBayLab     date_time temp_c humidity_rh dew_point            file_name
1         1 3/22/19 20:51   14.0        47.0       2.9 KasBayLab_050319.csv
2         2 3/22/19 21:06    7.0        67.0       1.3 KasBayLab_050319.csv
3         3 3/22/19 21:21    4.0        81.0       1.0 KasBayLab_050319.csv
4         4 3/22/19 21:36    3.5        86.0       1.4 KasBayLab_050319.csv
5         5 3/22/19 21:51    3.5        87.5       1.6 KasBayLab_050319.csv
6         6 3/22/19 22:06    3.0        88.0       1.2 KasBayLab_050319.csv
>

Comment: @sydney3989: please do not use `head()`. Make sure that you read the link G5W shared

Answer (score 0):

As others indicated, it is easy to add new data to a graph using `points()` or `lines()`. One thing to be careful about is how you format the axes as they will not be automatically adjusted to fit any new data you input using `points()` and the like.

I've included a small example below that you can copy, paste, run, and examine. Pay attention to why the first plot fails to produce what you want (axes are bad). Also note how I set this example up generally - by making fake data that showcase the same "problem" you are having. Doing this is often a better strategy than simply pasting in your data since it forces you to think about the core component of the problem you are facing.

```
#for same result each time
set.seed(1234)
#make data
set1<-data.frame("date1" = seq(1,10),
                 "temp1" = rnorm(10))
set2<-data.frame("date2" = seq(8,17),
                 "temp2" = rnorm(10, 1, 1))

#first attempt fails
#plot one
plot(set1$date1, set1$temp1, type = "b")
#add points - oops only three showed up bc the axes are all wrong
lines(set2$date2, set2$temp2, type = "b")

#second attempt
#adjust axes to fit everything (set to min and max of either dataset)
plot(set1$date1, set1$temp1,
     xlim = c(min(set1$date1,set2$date2),max(set1$date1,set2$date2)),
     ylim = c(min(set1$temp1,set2$temp2),max(set1$temp1,set2$temp2)),
     type = "b")
#now add the other points
lines(set2$date2, set2$temp2, type = "b")

# we can even add regression lines
abline(reg = lm(set1$temp1 ~ set1$date1))
abline(reg = lm(set2$temp2 ~ set2$date2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help